# How to make subclasses automatically call superclass methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a new developer of c# and I'm using unity3d to develop a game.
I design an interface to implement the skill system in game. But I find some trouble. Here are a lot of `Skill` classes, and I must call `show()` method manually inside their `apply`.

```
interface ISkill
{
    void apply();
}

class Base
{
    protected string name { get; set; }
    protected void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("show:"+name);
    }
}

class Skill1 : Base, ISkill
{
    public Skill1()
    {
        name = "skill1";
    }
    public void apply()
    {
        show();
        Console.WriteLine("skill1 apply");
    }

}
class Skill2 : Base, ISkill
{
    public Skill2()
    {
        name = "skill2";
    }
    public void apply()
    {
        show();
        Console.WriteLine("skill2 apply");
    }

}
Skill3
Skill4
etc.. 

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISkill skill = new Skill2();
        skill.apply();

    }
}
```

How to modify my code so that the all `SkillX` classes can automatically call `show()` method in `apply()` method?

Comment: Do you want to call `show` method manually, correct? You need to remove its calls from `apply` method.

Comment: One way you can do it is find all the classes in the assembly that implements `ISkill` and `foreach` it. Though not sure if you wanna do that

Comment: I think ```call show() in apply()``` is redundant.
I want to inject some code to make it automatically, but I have no ideas

Comment: The only way this makes sense is to make `Base` implement `ISkill`, mark the method as `virtual` and call `show()` from within its body. `Skill1`, `2`, etc then just have to override `apply` and call `base.apply()`. Does this save you any lines? Not really: you still have to "manually" call `base.apply()`, but if you ever have additional common behavior like that you still only need the one super call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard solution for this is [template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Base class implements method as "template" that forces derived classes to provide particular step(s) for that method. In your case the `Base` class should implement `Apply` method that calls `Show` first and than delegates the rest to derived classes by forcing them to provide implementation of the second part via `abstract void ApplyImplementation()`:

```
interface ISkill
{
    void Apply();
}

public abstract class Base
{
    protected string name { get; set; }
    protected Base(string name)
    {
       this.name = name;
    }

    protected void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("show:"+name);
    }

    // "template" method. 
    public void Apply()
    {
        Show(); 
        ApplyImplementation();
    }

    // derived class must implement that method
    protected abstract void ApplyImplementation();
}

class Skill1 : Base, ISkill
{
    public Skill1()
    {
        name = "skill1";
    }
    protected override void ApplyImplementation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("skill1 apply");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I had in mind, although I'd be tempted to make `Show()` virtual so that derived classes can do something different if needs be.

Comment: You can still make `Show` virtual.

Answer (score 0):

No general solution, other than trying to pull the commonality across different classes to the base.

In your case, since the only differences among the `apply()` seems to be the skill name, and you already have it as an instance property, you can pull the `apply` up to the `Base`, and have the same implementation across all the child classes of `Base`.

```
interface ISkill
{
    void apply();
}

class Base : ISkill
{
    protected string name { get; set; }
    protected Base(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void apply()
    {
        show();
        Console.WriteLine(name + " apply");
    }

    private void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("show:"+name);
    }
}

class Skill1 : Base
{
    public Skill1(): base("skill1"){}    
}
class Skill2 : Base
{
    public Skill2(): base("skill2"){}    
}
```